# Объявления countера в цикле

Tags: циклы, переменные, c++

**Какая конструкция более эффективная?**

```
int a, n = 10;

for(a = 0; a < n; a++)
{
    //.........
}
```

---

```
int n = 10;

for(int a = 0; a < n; a++)
{
    //.........
}
```

Мое мнение - если цикл используется один раз, то лучше объявлять (int a), а если несколько раз  то просто (a) везде. Думаю, связано с памятью, помогите разобраться

Comment: @risonyo, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строго говоря, разница нет, если только конструктор счётчика не делает какие-то огромные вычисления(99,9%).

А даже если и делает, то подобные *мелкие* оптимизации должны делать компиляторы. Если вы в цикле будете пузырьком сортировать, то прироста скорости точно не увидите ;-)

+Подобный подход создаст дополнительную глобальную переменную, в которой нет необходимости, что не очень хорошо.

Скажу следующее: не забивайте себе голову подобнобными вещами, это не тот код, который надо оптимизировать.

p.s. Преждевременная оптимизация -- тяжкий грех.

Comment: Даже если a будет объявлена глобально (хотя, я уверен, risonyo собирался разместить её локально), но использоваться только один раз, как счетчик цикла, то компилятор скорее всего сделает её регистровой переменной.

Преждевременная оптимизация, конечно, зло, но определенных рекомендаций (не обязательно связанных с оптимизацией) придерживаться нужно (про те же самые глобальные переменные).

Answer (score -2):

Если вы используйте тип int. И самих циклов for будет более 10000000. вот так вот

```
for (10000000) {
    for (a = 0; a < n; a++) { } // это быстрее
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) { } // это медленнее
}
```

В остальных случаях разница составляет наносекунды. И тратить на это время бессмысленно и всегда следует использовать `for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)`.

Comment: поверьте, если только не используется какой то допотопный компилятор, то разницы не будет между этим циклами никакой. Более того, если тела цикла нет, компиляторм может вобще выбросить оба и в этом случае первый будет дольше. Почему? а просто во втором случае видно, что переменная `a` не используется по выходу с цикла, ее значение не важно. В первом придется сделать одно присваивание.

Comment: Ну вообще не стоит учитывать оптимизацию в компиляторах.
1) человек хочет понять логику работы.
2) Оптимизация может быть отключена и эти вот пустые циклы не будут удалены.
3) Вместо int он может использовать самописный тип, в котором конструктор например каждый раз выделяет память на 10кб, а деструктор удаляет.

Comment: говорить о эффективности кода и не говорить о том, как работает компилятор (хотя бы в общих чертах) как то неэтично. Это как о сферическом коне в вакууме.

Comment: Но он не сказал какой компилятор.
Я не разбираюсь в машинном коде.
В моём понимании переменная a в таком цикле
for(int a = 0; a < n; a++){}
будет создаваться не в оперативной памяти, а в кеше процессора?
Это компилятор переместит её в кеш в результате оптимизации?

Comment: >>Но он не сказал какой компилятор.

А вариантов то на самом деле не так и много. gcc, msvc, clang, intel c++, хотя обычно первыми двумя все и оканчивается.

>> будет создаваться не в оперативной памяти, а в кеше процессора?
в кеш попадают те участки оперативной памяти, которые часто используются. А просто так создать ее в кеше не получиться. Другое дело, если эта переменная не будет использоваться внутри цикла, а сам цикл достаточно маленький, то компилятор может просто использовать регистр процессора - а вот обращение к регистру процессора - это уже действительно очень быстро.

Comment: я просто задал вопрос так как есть, и даже не не знаю ничего толком об оптимизации, только краем уха) просто интересно стало, какая конструкция эффективнее; Герберт Шилдт в свой книги например один раз толко создает переменную и гонит по всей программе, а в видео обучалках в основном все for(int a = 0; a < n; a++){} пишут, поэтому и сложился такой вопрос у меня ;)

Comment: В целом - пишите код попроще. Нужна переменная - объявите. Если в коде будет тридцать циклов один за одним и у каждого будет своя переменная, то ничего плохого не произойдет (ну кроме потери читаемости). Современные компиляторы куда оптимальнее оптимизируют простой код, чем "хитро оптимизированный руками".

Comment: Желательно для всех циклов использовать одну и туже переменную.
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){}

чтобы не путаться
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){}
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){}
for(int w = 0; w < n; w++){}
for(int q = 0; q < n; q++){}

Comment: @manking откуда такие странные идеи? Имена переменных желательно давать по смыслу задачи (если там есть какие-то намёки на имя). И желательность "одной переменной" ("чтобы не путаться") не имеет смысла.

Comment: так что ли?

for(int счётчик_вектора = 0; счётчик_вектора <= vector.size()-1; счётчик_вектора++){}

for(int счётчик_файлов = 0; счётчик_файлов <= files.size()-1; счётчик_файлов++){}

...